# Hello ! Confusion in the if else statement of addItem function. Can anyone suggest cleaner code?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

This code felt a bit tricky but my confusion is mainly in the ifElse part of the addItem function.
               I am not able to figure out the ifElse statement wherein I have passed checkDuplicate function as a condition and understanding the parameters passed to it.

```
     let toDoList = [];

    function addItem(arr)
    {   
        let userAns = prompt('What will you do today ?');

        let formatted = userAns.toUpperCase();

        if(checkDuplicates(arr, formatted))   // Confusion started here
        {
            arr.push(formatted);
        }

        else
        {
            prompt('Item already exists');
        }

    }

    function checkDuplicates(arr1, arrElem)
    {
        let elemExists = false;

        let index = arr1.indexOf(arrElem);

        if(index === -1)
        {
            elemExists = true;
        }

        else
        {
            elemExists = false;
        }

        return elemExists;
    }

    addItem(toDoList);

    addItem(toDoList);

    addItem(toDoList);

    addItem(toDoList);

    console.log(toDoList);
```

Comment: Head to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Calling a custom 11-line function looks a bit unnecessary when you can achieve the same thing with a simple `.includes` test (a built-in function to check whether an array includes an item):

```
let toDoList = [];
function addItem(arr) {
  let userAns = prompt('What will you do today ?');
  let formatted = userAns.toUpperCase();
  if (!arr.includes(formatted))  {
    arr.push(formatted);
  } else {
    prompt('Item already exists');
  }
}
```

It's pretty self-explanatory - call `.includes` on the array you want to look at, and pass one argument, the item whose existence you want to check for in that array.

Answer (score 0):

`checkDuplicates` checks wether the `arr` contains `formatted` already, if yes it returns `false` if not it returns `true`. In that case the `if`branch gets executed and `formatted` gets phshed to `arr`. Therefore it won't add duplicates.

---

Sidenote: `checkDuplicates` is unneccessary, there is a builtin for that:

```
 // read as "if arr not includes formatted"
 if(!arr.includes(formatted))
    arr.push(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need the function `checkDuplicates()`
- Don't make other variable `formatted` just apply `.toUpperCase()` to `prompt(...)`
- Instead of `if-else` use ternary operators
- Use loop to call the function `addItem`
- Use `includes()` instead of `indexOf()`

```js
    let toDoList = [];

    function addItem(arr)
    {   
        let userAns = prompt('What will you do today ?').toUpperCase();
        !arr.includes(userAns) ? arr.push(userAns) :   prompt('Item already exists')
    }
    for(let i = 0;i<4;i++) addItem(toDoList);
    console.log(toDoList);
```